# Working with lists - Python

Tags: python, list

i ran into a little logic problem and trying to figure it out.

my case is as follows:

i have a list of items each item represents a Group

i need to create a set of nested groups,

so, for example:

```
myGroups = ["head", "neck", "arms", "legs"]
```

i need to get them to be represented like this: 
(if you can imaging a folder structure)

```
head 
  |_> neck 
        |_> arms 
              |_>legs
```

and so on until i hit the last element.

what i thought would work (but don't know really how to advance here) is:

```
def createVNTgroups(self, groupsData): 
    for i in range(len(groupsData)): 
        print groupsData[i] 
        for q in range(1, len(groupsData)): 
            print groupsData[q]
```

but in this case, i am running over same elements in 'i' that i already took with 'q'.

could someone give me a hint?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what your output is supposed to be. An object? Or just text printed to the screen in some specific format?

Comment: this function performs an object creation, basically i get array, and each element than is calling another method to perform object creation using API, but each element in the LIST must be a sub-element of a previous one. As the output, in my application, i am expecting to see a tree of folders similar to the diagram i made

Comment: Do you just want to iterate `for q in range(len(groupsData[i])): print groupsData[i][q]`? I.e., `for q in groupsData[i]: print q`?

Comment: Sorry, could you add the complete expected response?

Comment: Yes. I need to itterate through the list, but to store each previous value so my next element in list can reference as its parent

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you want a nested structure. For this case, you can use a recursive function:

```
myGroups = ["head", "neck", "arms", "legs"] 

def createVNTgroups(alist):
    temp = alist[:]                 # needed because lists are mutable 
    first = [temp.pop(0)]           # extract first element from list
    if temp:                        # if the list still contains more items,
        second = [createVNTgroups(temp)]   # do it recursively
        return first + second       # returning the second object attached to the first.
    else:                           # Otherwise,
        return first                # return the last element


print createVNTgroups(myGroups)
```

this produces a nested list:

```
['head', ['neck', ['arms', ['legs']]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you were looking for?

```
>>> m
['head', 'neck', 'arms', 'legs']
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:[x,y][::-1] if x!=y else [x], m[::-1],m[-1])
['head', ['neck', ['arms', ['legs']]]]
```

Comment: yes, i sort of got to the similar conclusion, now, how do i walk through it? how would i access "arms" there? Or just print out each element?

Comment: What do you want to do? I mean- what output are you looking for?